# How to analyze log files with regexp? alternatives?

Tags: regex, logging, analysis

I want to analyze some logs for some statisics of usage.
Basically what I wanna do is use regexp to ease the pain of analysis

So I have a text file with logs something along this

```
2011-09-17 09:16:33,531 INFO  [someJava.class.special] sendRequest: fromGevoName=null, ctrlPageId=fooBar, actionId=search,
2011-09-17 09:16:33,976 INFO  [someJavaB.class] fooBar
2011-09-17 09:16:33,982 DEBUG [someOtherJava.class] abc blabala
2011-09-17 09:16:33,987 INFO  [someJava.class.special] sendRequest completed: fromGevoName=XYZ, toPageId=fooBar, userId=someUser
```

.... 
I want to count the occurrences of all words at position

`[someJava.class.special]  ctrlPageId=....`

in this case fooBar and only this occurrences. There are many different fooBar and I want to count how often one occurred.

My idea was to replace with a matching group and repeat it, something along this

```
((?s).*\[someJava.class.special\] sendRequest: fromGevoname=.* ctrlPageId=([^,]*)(?-s).*)*
```

and replace it with the matching group `\2`

Afterwards analyse the list in excel.
But my greptool does not repeat the regexp, it only matches once. I use grepWin, is there maybe a different tool / regexp for this?

Well it basically was a problem of wingrep or grepwin. The modifier (?s) which enables linebreaks on dots or disables it (?-s) does not work if you use it repeatedly. 
So I exchanged the regexp with something along this:

```
([\n-\[\(\]\.,:0-9a-zA-Z]).*\[someJava.class.special\] sendRequest: fromGevoname=.* ctrlPageId ([^,]*)(?-s).*
```

so basically i exchanged the first linebreakmatching dot with all symbols which might occur in the string including linebreaks. It works... i'm sure there is a better solution, always open for it

Comment: i didn't understand your requirement well. are you willing to get all lines containing `[someJava.class.special] sendRequest: fromGevoname=ANYTHING ctrlPageId=ANYTHING` or replace ANYTHING to CERTAIN THING?

Comment: i'm willing to get all lines containing ctrlPageId=ANYTHING

Comment: then doesn't `grep -E "ctrlPageId=.*" file` give you all lines?

Comment: it probably does but I run on a windows machine without the possibility to download or install a program like win grep :-D yipie

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand, but if the output you are looking for is:
`someJava fooBar`

Something like this should work (php script):

```
<?php
$log = file_get_contents('file.log')
preg_match_all("#\[(?<className>\w+)\.class(.special)?\](.*?)ctrlPageId=(?<controllerName>\w+)#i", $log, $m);

for ($i=0; $i < count($m[0]); $i++) {
  echo $m['className'][$i] . ' ' . $m['controllerName'][$i] . "\n";
}
```

Comment: i am sure php is cool but I don't use it. I updated my question with a solution